# How to set custom headers on Express and receive it on axios

Tags: reactjs, express, request, axios, header

I am trying to set a custom header on every response my Express api sends, so I wrote a simple middleware:

```
app.use((request, response, next) => {
  response.setHeader("custom-header", "value");
  next();
});
```

But when I inspect the headers received on my ReactJS application using axios interceptor, it simply doesn't appear. Here is my interceptor:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3333"
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    console.log(response.headers);
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error)
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default api;
```

Just in case it may be relevant, my express app also uses [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) and [express.json](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#express.json) middlewares, but I already tryied removing them and still I wasn't able to receive the header on the client.

What would be the appropriate way to set and receive a custom header on every request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So ironically a few minutes after posting the question I finally found the solution (which I was looking for for hours):

Turns out it is necessary to configure [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) on the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware configuration, like this:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    exposedHeaders: ["custom-header"]
  })
);
```